# How to count every 1000 observation in data set SAS

Tags: sas

I have some data set ranked by some variable.

I need to take  every 1000 observation from the beginning and count in which field1=1, then count next 1000 observations in the same way.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly what you want.

You could try a datastep like this

```
data result (Keep=countob obnr);

retain obnr 1000;
retain countob 0;

set mydata;
if field1=1 then
countob=countob+1;

if mod(_n_,1000) = 0 then do;
output;
obnr=obnr+1000;
countob=0;
end;
run;
```

this would lead to a result like this:

```
obnr | countob
------------
1000 | 247
2000 | 325
3000 | 198
```

obnr is obviously optional...

Comment: one thing that I have obnr in my result set only 1000 in every row

Comment: you could also try simply obnr=_n_; instead of obnr=obnr+1000; that should lead to the same result. Otherwise i am not sure why it stays at 1000 if you copied my code...

Answer (score 1):

Another, slightly shorter, way, utilizing `CEIL`-function and `PROC FREQ`-procedure:

```
data want;
  set have;
  thousand=ceil(_N_/1000)*1000;
run;
proc freq data=want;
  tables thousand / out=want;
  where field1=1;
run;
```